# Where did the matching transfer go wrong?

Tags: equation-solving

For the equation:

```
4 m^2 + 6 n == 1 + n^2
```

shifting the term yields this:

```
4 m^2 == 1 + n^2 - 6 n
```

I tried this, but how did it turn out to be false?

```
4 m^2 + 6 n == 1 + n^2 /. 
 k_.*m^2 + t_.*n == a_ + s_.*n^2 :> k == a + s - t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

```
list = CoefficientList[4 m^2 + 6 n == 1 + n^2 /. Equal -> Subtract ,,m^2]
m^2 list[[2]] == -list[[1]]
(*4 m^2 == 1 - 6 n + n^2*)
```